# Dynamic templates in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm about to make a dynamic website in Django so that user can change the template the website is based upon....for new users, they'll have to choose a template they like from a menu, after which this is stored in a cookie for future reference.  I however don't know how to do this....any ideas.

Comment: Is an alternate template directory the preferred solution? It would be much easier to maintain the same template and simply swap out the CSS link referenced in the template based on the user's preference. This would allow for vast changes in layout, but perhaps there is a use case I'm not aware of that would make the templates directory swap necessary...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Templates are text files in a directory on your server.

The menu is a list of directories.

The specific template to be loaded is named in your `render_to_response` calls in each view function.

It's wonderfully quite simple and elegant.

You never need to do a template "swap".  You can simply have all the templates you ever want in a  template search path.  All can be available to all users at all times.  You just provide `directory_name/template_name`.  All handled for you.

Don't mess with explicit cookies.  Django already does this for you.  See [chapter 12](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/#cn222) of the Django Book.

Use the [Profiles extension](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) and put the selected template directory name in the user's profile.

Answer (score 2):

When user selects a template, store the template name/ some sort of alias in the cookie. When the user loads the page again, in the view function, check for template identifier in the cookie. If the identifier is present, retrieve the actual template path and pass it to the `render_to_response` function.